# How can create assoc 3D Array of Array?

Tags: swift

I tried create Array 3D but i still don't know how to create one ?

```
var array = [ 
    "10001": [
        "last_index": 0, //Int
        "conteiner": [
            "id_from": 321, // Int
            "val2": "string text" // String
            ]
        ]
   ]
```

Comment: That's a dictionary. What error do you get? Be more descriptive, you want others to help you.

Comment: I did this in playground without error, just i can't see result when i put `print(array["10001"]["last_index"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in Swift 2.0:

```
let array : [String : [String : Any]] = [
    "10001": [
        "last_index": 0, //Int
        "conteiner": [
            "id_from": 321 as Any, // Int
            "val2": "string text" as Any // String
        ]
    ]
]

array["10001"]?["last_index"]    // 0
```